# Definitions of torch ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, definitions

Well, I find myself in a tangled web of references, definitions and doubt.  How do I get myself into these things? Get ready for a rollercoaster of definitions.

An FGC ring is a commutative ring whose finitely generated modules are all direct sums of cyclic modules.  One special species of FGC ring is called a "torch ring."

In

> Vámos, Peter. "The Decomposition of Finitely Generated Modules and Fractionally Self‐Injective Rings." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 2.2 (1977): 209-220.

the author writes (I paraphrase slightly):

### Torch definition 1

> Thus we say that $R$ is a torch ring if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $R$ is not local
> 2. The localization at each maximal ideal is a valuation ring.
> 3. $R$ has a unique minimal, nonzero, prime ideal $P$ with linearly ordered submodules.

"valuation ring" throughout this post refers to a ring with linearly ordered ideals, regardless if it is an integral domain or not.

Now, every other book and article I read says the definition of a torch ring is this:

### Torch definition 2

> 1. $R$ is not local
> 2. $R$ is Bezout
> 3. The localization at each maximal ideal is an "almost maximal valuation ring"
> 4. $R/P$ is an $h$-local domain
> 5. $R$ has a unique minimal, nonzero, prime ideal $P$ with linearly ordered submodules.

"$h$-local domain" means that each nonzero prime ideal is contained in a unique maximal ideal, and each ideal is contained in only finitely many maximal ideals.

"almost maximal valuation ring" means that every quotient by a nonzero ideal is a "maximal valuation ring" meaning it's a valuation ring  satisfying a criterion on solvability of systems of congruences.

### These are apparently different

Both of them are claimed to be what Wiegand and Shores called "?-rings", but there is apparently a difference.

Under definition 2, $R$ being Bezout causes its localizations to be Bezout local rings, which are indeed valuation rings, so the second definition implies the first.

At the end of Vámos's paper:

> Note that an FGCF ring is just an FSI Bezout ring (Theorem A) and therefore Theorems A and B provide a characterization of FGCF rings.

I think Vámos's thusly defined torch ring is strictly weaker and is used to characterize FSI rings rather than FGC rings.

FGCF stands for "finitely generated modules have a canonical form," which refers to them having a structure like in the usual structure theorem for f.g. modules over a PID.  Obviously FGCF->FGC but at the time I think there was some question whether or not they were equivalent. He notes in this paper that "if an FGC ring has finitely many minimal primes, then FGC->FGCF as well" and I see references later that seem to confirm that this was indeed proven.

So I think the source of my initial confusion is that nothing I read made this distinction, especially [this obituary](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1112/blms.12689) which uses definition 1 and uses it in a characterization of FGC rings.  I guess an oversight was made.

### Lingering questions

Clearly Bezout + torch(1) is closer to torch(2), but I'm not clear on how it buys us the other two conditions.  (The almost maximality of the localizations, and the $h$-local condition on $R/P$.)

I'm hoping someone can clear up how this implication works, or maybe demonstrate the assertions have a problem.